# Delete all approval queue comments

Tags: comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete all unpublished comments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9904/how-to-delete-all-unpublished-comments)

I have been hit by spammers and now have like over 10k comments sitting in the approval queue. Is there a way to delete all of the comments in approval queue in Drupal 6?